# Analyze and update dynamic table macro VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to make a macro to analyze and update the dynamic table located in the second sheet of the workbook ("TD"), i made a macro but it displays the error '1004' ERROR DEFINED BY THE APPLICATION OR OBJECT, hope you can help me.

```
Dim wsTD As Worksheet
Dim wbWs As Workbook

Set wbWs = ActiveWorkbook
Set wsTD = wbWs.Worksheets("TD")
wbWs.PivotTables(“TablaDinámica1”).PivotCache.Refresh
wbWs.PivotTables(“TablaDinámica2”).PivotCache.Refresh
```

Comment: Change the smart/curly quotes to straight quotes.

Comment: @BigBen i changed it but the error showed.

Comment: So you changed to `"TablaDinámica1"` and `"TablaDinámica2"`.?

Comment: Yeah @BigBen and had no success

Comment: Thanks for the solution @PEH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to find your pivot table in a workbook `wbWs` not in a worksheet `wsTD`. Change it to:

```
wsTD.PivotTables("TablaDinámica1").PivotCache.Refresh
wsTD.PivotTables("TablaDinámica2").PivotCache.Refresh
```